# jQuery: scrollspy() and scrollTop() not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some scripts under `<script>` tag, but nothing seems to be functional. What am I doing wrong? Here is the link of CodePen: https://codepen.io/msrumon/pen/EJyYxP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look in the console, lots of errors.  As documented with bootstrap you need to include popper.js

Comment: Doesn't it work in codepen only? If so, it won't work when you include JS such a way. There's Settings button in the top right of the codepen's page, there you can include jQuery.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RORwyb -- now it works

Comment: you are missing pictures , bootstrap some scripts...

Comment: @AlexK. But bootstrap.bundle.js includes popper.js

Comment: @Arfeo, No, it doesn't work in both CodePen and my localhost. And scrolltop is working in your pen, but not scrollspy. Can you recheck?

Comment: Well, you had a problem, I just gave a hint. `scrollTop` now works. I would check scrollspy, if I only knew, what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did some tweaking, and found that removing all the `min` and `slim` texts from URLs was what I needed. So this is my final contents inside `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Chris Dortch</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Thanks to all who advised me something. And kudos to @Arfeo for helping me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace bootstrap and jquery cdn with following cdn there is something wrong with your cdn thats why it is giving error

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </script>

      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```